# how do I reboot my network card in batch if ping fail

Tags: batch, script, network-adapter, bash-scripting

I have a problem with my network that I can't fix for the moment but rebooting my network card when I loos my internet connection works for the moment so I would like to know how I make a script that ping ether 8.8.8.8 or 127.0.0.1 and reboot the network card if a ping fails. (So I don't have to babysit it)

Comment: What OS are you using? You can restart the network with 'systemctl restart network' if you are using systemd on linux. You would have to make sure the script has root privileges as well

Answer (score 1):

Successful `ping` will return code 0, whilst failed connections will return
code 1 and above.

See this (untested) snippet to ping every minute:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    systemctl restart network
  fi
sleep 60
done
```

`systemctl` was recommended in a comment above, but the command in your distribution
may differ, and `sudo` might also be required.